# Updating different columns with their corresponding where clause

Tags: sql-server

Let say Table1 and Table 2, Table 1 with columns DDcl1, DDcl2, DDcl3, ...

I need to update these tables with

```
update A
set DDcl1 = 'Y'
from Table1 A join Table2 B
on A.id = B.id
where B.Ref = 'cl1'

update A
set DDcl2 = 'Y'
from Table1 A join Table2 B
on A.id = B.id
where B.Ref = 'cl2'

update A
set DDcl3 = 'Y'
from Table1 A join Table2 B
on A.id = B.id
where B.Ref = 'cl3'
```

Is there a way to update these tables with their corresponding where clauses in much easier way? I need to update more than 10 columns and with the above query it will take me for long writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update A 
  set [DDcl1]= case when B.Ref = 'cl1'  then 'Y' else 'N' end,
      [DDcl2]= case when B.Ref = 'cl2'  then 'Y' else 'N' end
--............. Add more codition 
from Table1 A join Table2 B
on A.id = B.id
```

Comment: may I ask which one is faster, your answer or my multiple updates above?

Comment: I did not test the perf since i did not have the tables and data.I am assuming the above sql b/c you are doing all in one script. Make sure that you have index on the a.Id, B.id and  B.Ref.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. It is assuming that the original value in each of the columns needs to be preserved. If it does not, then it could be a set value in the ELSE, like 'N'.
Also, I added a where clause to minimize the number of updates, not sure if this applies in your specific case.

```
    UPDATE A
    SET DDcl1 = CASE WHEN B.Ref = 'cl1' THEN 'Y' ELSE DDcl1 END,
        DDcl2 = CASE WHEN B.Ref = 'cl2' THEN 'Y' ELSE DDCL2 END,
        DDcl3 = CASE WHEN B.Ref = 'cl3' THEN 'Y' ELSE DDcl3 END
    -- Additional cases
    FROM Table1 A join Table2 B
    on A.id = B.id
    WHERE B.Ref in ('cl1','cl2','cl3')
```

Comment: Thanks :)). This is the same as Hiten004 said but will minimize the number of updates.

Comment: It will minimize updates, and it will also not overwrite whatever value is currently in DDclXX fields.